# After Upgrade to Magento 2.2.2: Duplicate entry '0-0-0-0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `salesrule_product_attribute` () VALUES ()

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.2

If I Upgrade Magento from 2.1.8 to 2.2.2 and run `setup:upgrade` I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-0-0-0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `salesrule_product_attribute` () VALUES ()
```

If I truncate all salesrule tables it works, but I can't do this on a production environment. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the file `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/ResourceModel/Rule.php`.

The method `setActualProductAttributes` inserts empty `VALUES()` if `$data` is empty.

This can be fixed by overriding the Model and replace

```
$connection->insertMultiple($this->getTable('salesrule_product_attribute'), $data);
```

with:

```
if(count($data > 0 )) {
    $connection->insertMultiple($this->getTable('salesrule_product_attribute'), $data);
}
```

Comment: Unable to apply data patch ...  Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable ...    Just deleting that line rather than if - seems to worked